# wrong number of arguments Contact#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this error :

> ArgumentError in Contact#create
>
> wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2)

it show me this line from my view

```
  <%= @contact.errors.full_message.each do |message| %>
```

My create method in contact_controller take no arguments

**contact_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @contact = Contact.all
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
      flash[:notice] = "Welcome"
      redirect_to "/"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "You filled wrong the form"
      render 'connection'
    end
  end
```

and i'm supposed to display those message from my model

**contact.rb**

```
validates :firstname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30, minimum:2,
    too_long: "30 characters is the maximum allowed.", too_short: "2 characters is the minimum allowed." }

validates :lastname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50, minimum:2,
    too_long: "50 characters is the maximum allowed.", too_short: "2 characters is the minimum allowed." }
    
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: {message: "Email is already subscribed"}, length: { maximum: 40, minimum:7,
    too_long: "40 characters is the maximum allowed.", too_short: "7 characters is the minimum allowed.",},
    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
    
validates :password, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30, minimum:6,
    too_long: "30 characters is the maximum allowed.", too_short: "6 characters is the minimum allowed." }
```

I do not understand what arguments ruby wants. anyone know what is it ?

Comment: Is `full_message` rather than `full_messages` a typo?  I assume you don't actually want `full_message`

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `full_messages` not `full_message`

`full_message` is a method that takes a key and an abbreviated message and combines them, so it needs two arguments...

```
@contact.errors.full_message(:sausage, 'is too dry') 
=> "Sausage is too dry"
```